# (C# with NUnit 2.6.4) [Setup] running for every test case

Tags: c#, web-services, nunit

I have my Global Setup as below

```
public class GlobalSetup
{
    [SetUp]
    public void setUp()
    {
      // Setup code
    }
}
```

and my test cases as below

```
[TestFixture]
public class Products : GlobalSetup
{
    [Test, Description("Test description here")]
    public void GetProductsByProductID()
    {

    }

    [Test]
    public void GetHeader()
    {

    }

    [Test]
    public void GetMyProducts()
    {

    }
}
```

Though the setup is running it is running once for every test case. I want the setup to run only once for the entire test suite. Can you guys please help me how i can run the setup only once for my entire suite.

Also, when i have used the GlobalSetUp file as below, then the setup method was running twice for each test case.

**Note:** I am using NUnit 2.6.4

Comment: Look at the [SetupFixture](https://nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.6.3) documentation.

Comment: @JeroenHeier But i see in SetupFixture this example it is marked at class level and Setup marked at method level. Can i mark [SetupFixture] at method level too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you want to run global setup once for the test suite, do you mean the TestFixture? I'll assume you do in my answer, but remember that the assembly is a test suite, each namespace is a test suite, etc.

To run global setup once for the fixture, before any tests are run. Change SetUp attribute in GlobalSetUp class to TestFixtureSetUp attribute. (If you were using NUnit 3.x, it would be OneTimeSetUp attribute)

If you mean something other than the test fixture, I can edit this answer for you.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, that was all i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

NUnit [`SetUp`](https://nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.6.3) attribute causes method execution before each test method.

What you need is a [`TestFixtureSetUp`](https://nunit.org/index.php?p=fixtureSetup&r=2.6.3) attribute, that is used to mark one-time setup method.

Comment: But i see in [SetupFixture](https://nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.6.3) this example it is marked at class level and [Setup](https://nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.6.3) marked at method level. Can i mark [SetupFixture] at method level too?

Comment: @CodeFuller misspoke. A SetUpFixture is a fixture, i.e. a class. It contains a SetUp method in NUnit 2.x or a OneTimeSetUp method in NUnit 3.x.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up SetUpFixture with a TestFixtureSetUp. Corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @CodeFuller it was quite helpful